# IBM Domino Server how to set Turkish Character with FP10

Tags: lotus-domino

I have installed FP10 on to Domino Server 9.0.1. After installing FP10 If anyone sends mail from outside of our mail domain It looks like we have Turkish Characters problem. O could not find which settings i have to do. 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Mail subject looks like this 
=?utf-8?B?UkU6IFNFTUEgR8OcTEzDnCBBVEEtxLBwb3Rla2xpIEJhbmthIEtyZWRpc2kg?= =?utf-8?Q?hk.?=

[image: Mail Screen]

Comment: You need to install the latest interim fix (9.0.1 FP10 IF2).

Comment: I have 9.0.1 FP10 IF1. IF1 can solve my issue or do i have to install IF2?

Comment: My mistake. IF1 is the latest interim fix for Domino and it should solve your issue (see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963 and the fix JBAMAVKUPX)

Comment: Excellent, I added my comment as a response

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install interim fix 1 (IF1) for Domino 9.0.1 FP10. It should solve your issue - see [www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963) and the fix JBAMAVKUPX.